# Delphi - DBGrid doesn't display contents of ADO Table

Tags: delphi, ado, dbgrid

So I've tried to load all my ADO Tables into their respective DBGrids at run-time. I get no errors but nothing displays in the Grids? What am I doing wrong here?

**Code I'm using:**

```
procedure TfrmEntry.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  GridSetupContainer;
end;

procedure TfrmEntry.GridSetupContainer;
begin

  with dmArchive do
  begin
    GridSetup(dbgA16,dsr1660);
    GridSetup(dbgA2P1,dsrTwoPointOne);
    GridSetup(dbgAXKarts,dsrXKarts);
    GridSetup(dbgAHM,dsrHeavyMetals);
    GridSetup(dbgAHR,dsrHotrods);
    GridSetup(dbgAMIDA,dsrMidA);
    GridSetup(dbgAMIDB,dsrMidB);
    GridSetup(dbgAMinis,dsrMinis);
    GridSetup(dbgAPink,dsrPinkrods);
    GridSetup(dbgASpr,dsrSprints);
    GridSetup(dbgASR,dsrStockrods);
    GridSetup(dbgADev,dsrDev);
    GridSetup(dbgAV8,dsrV8);
    GridSetup(dbgALM,dsrLateModels);
  end;

  with dmRacers do
  begin
    GridSetup(dbgR16,dsr1660);
    GridSetup(dbgR2P1,dsrTwoPointOne);
    GridSetup(dbgRXKarts,dsrXKarts);
    GridSetup(dbgRHM,dsrHeavyMetals);
    GridSetup(dbgRHR,dsrHotrods);
    GridSetup(dbgRMIDA,dsrMidA);
    GridSetup(dbgRMIDB,dsrMidB);
    GridSetup(dbgRMini,dsrMinis);
    GridSetup(dbgRPink,dsrPinkrods);
    GridSetup(dbgRSP,dsrSprints);
    GridSetup(dbgRSR,dsrStockrods);
    GridSetup(dbgRDev,dsrDev);
    GridSetup(dbgRV8,dsrV8);
    GridSetup(dbgRLM,dsrLateModels);
  end;

end;

procedure TfrmEntry.GridSetup(grid: TDBGrid; source: TDataSource);
begin
  grid.DataSource:=source;
end;
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Kind Regards
PrimeBeat

Comment: You have shown the code that links DB grids to data sources. But are those data sources linked to data sets? How do you activate data sets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
procedure TfrmEntry.GridSetup(grid: TDBGrid; source: TDataSource);
begin
  grid.DataSource:=source;
  source.dataset.open; //this line!!! perhaps you don't open the table!, edited has sugested by Peter Wolf
end;
```